# laravel resource function model object instance parameter

Tags: php, laravel

```
public function show(Test $test)
{
    echo 555;
}
```

when I created a resource in laravel, in the controller I've found this method, but the parameter of this function and whats interesting is that it takes it as a Model object instance, but how can I really pass this object from the url, when the only thing that is available from there is the ID of the row in the database, I dont know maybe I'm missing something, but is it just for example there or is there a way of getting straight the model object instead of passing ID?

Comment: You can. It's [impllicit model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#implicit-binding)

Answer (score 0):

You can set default value for this function

```
public function show(Test $test=null)
{
    echo 555;
}
```